# Failed test is hanging Jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, docker, jenkins, mocha.js

I am making a pipeline on Jenkins to test and deploy my node.js application using Docker containers. But I am getting my pipeline stuck because a test is failing. The behaviour I would expect is pipeline finishes without executing next stages but it will not get stuck.

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '''docker build --tag my-web:$BUILD_NUMBER .
docker stop my-web&& docker rm my-web
echo "Build step finished"'''
      }
    }
    stage('Unit test') {
      steps {
        sh '''docker build -t my-web-test -f Dockerfile.test .
docker run --rm my-web-test
'''
      }
    }
    stage('Run') {
      steps {
        sh '''docker run --name my-web -p 3000:3000 my-web:$BUILD_NUMBER node /var/www/index.js &
'''
        echo 'RUNNING'
      }
    }
    stage('End') {
      steps {
        echo 'End of pipeline'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile.test**:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir /var/test
WORKDIR /var/test
COPY package.json /var/test/
RUN npm install && npm install -g mocha
COPY src/ /var/test/
CMD ["mocha", "tests/", "--recursive"]
```

**When I trigger the pipeline:**

- If I remove `Unit test` stage from pipeline everything works **OK** and application begins running.
- If I **do not** remove `Unit test` stage, testing stage begins and I get a result of 14 test passed and 1 failed but the pipeline hangs in this step so `Run` step never triggers and the pipeline keeps in `Running` status.

> **14 passing (2s)**
>
> **1 failing**
>
> **1**) Checking user first-time-login
>
> ```
>    Should redirect to change-password page:
>
>  Error: expected "Location" of "/dashboard/change-password", got "/dashboard"
>
>   at Test._assertHeader (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:249:12)
>
>   at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
>
>   at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
>
>   at localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
>
>   at /var/test/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:128:5
>
>   at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:728:3)
>
>   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:18)
>
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
>
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of mocha need to exit, otherwise the server keeps running so next stage is never reached.

```
mocha --exit
```